# Active directory Add-QADUser-what's the unique identifier?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am writing up a Powershell Script to automatically pulling info from one database to update Active Directory, e.g. adding new users.

I am new to Active Directory and am using [this useful graphic maps to link UI label to AD attributes](http://www.selfadsi.org/user-attributes-w2k8.htm)

I would expect the UserPrincipalName, e.g. **tina.Tana@example.com**, is the unique identifier of user accounts.

But during testing, it turns out otherwise. If I do:

```
$status = New-QADUser -FirstName 'Tina' -LastName 'Tana' -Name 'Tina A Tana' `
            -UserPrincipalName 'tina.tana@example.com' `
            -ParentContainer 'OU=OU2,OU=OU2,DC=example,DC=com'
$status = New-QADUser -FirstName 'Tina' -LastName 'Tana' -Name 'Tina B Tana' `
            -UserPrincipalName 'tina.tana@example.com' `
            -ParentContainer 'OU=OU2,OU=OU2,DC=example,DC=com'
```

2 accounts will be both created OK, with the only difference being the *-Name* field.

If I do:

```
$status = New-QADUser -FirstName 'Tina' -LastName 'Tana' -Name 'Tina Tana' `
            -UserPrincipalName 'tina.tana-1@example.com' `
            -ParentContainer 'OU=OU2,OU=OU2,DC=example,DC=com'
$status = New-QADUser -FirstName 'Tina' -LastName 'Tana' -Name 'Tina Tana' `
            -UserPrincipalName 'tina.tana-2@example.com' `
            -ParentContainer 'OU=OU2,OU=OU2,DC=example,DC=com'
```

The difference is only the `-UserPrincipalName` . the 2nd add-user will fail, PS says user already created. I tried other combinations, but it indicates -Name must be unique, other fields do not matter.

Have I missed anything? It seems to me that people can have a same name, but the when creating an account, the user principal name SHOULD be unique. (When you manually create a new user AD account using *AD User and Computers* GUI tool, if you give a same logon name (i.e. userPrincipalName) to different people, the tool will tell you you must give a different logon name.

So why is it different when doing it from Powershell using Quest Add-QADUser? Why when doing it from Powershell, the command will be executed successfully?

puzzled!
Many thx for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this [microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251359/en-us) and this [msdn library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Active Directory itself does not enforce uniqueness of a UPN. The process that creates or modifies the UPN is responsible to check for uniqueness (this is done by querying the global catalog). 
Probably `New-Qaduser` doesn't do this check.

Usually  the unique identifyer for an user is the `samAccountName`.
If you don't set the `UserPrincipalName` AD build a default one:
the user principal name has two parts: the UPN prefix (the user account name) and the UPN suffix (a DNS domain name). The parts are joined together by the at sign (@) symbol to make the complete UPN. For example, the user Someone who has an account in the Example domain would have a UPN of "someone@example.com".